How to show that an edge in a plane graph being adjacent to 2 faces implies it's part of a cycle
Suppose we have a finite plane graph. I wish to show that an edge is adjacent to 2 faces if and only if it belongs to a cycle.
Belongs to a cycle implies it's adjacent to 2 faces is a straightforward application of Jordan curve theorem. However I don't know how to prove the other direction even though it seems very intuitive.

Maybe you can use the fact that there are only two kind of faces in a planar graph, namely faces bound by cycles, and exactly one unbounded face.

@HackR That's false, though. The unbounded face is not different from the others, but faces (bounded or unbounded) do not need to be bound by cycles.

@MishaLavrov I might be misinterpreting something, becvause in a planar embedding, aren't faces always bound by cycles (except the outer face)?

@HackR In a $2$-connected graph, that is guaranteed. If all we know is that the graph is connected, the boundary of a face is a closed walk (but not necessarily a cycle). If we do not even know that the graph is connected, the boundary of a face could consist of several disjoint closed walks. All of these facts treat the outer face just like any others, because it's not combinatorially different: an inversion through a point can turn any face of the plane embedding into the outer face.

@MishaLavrov Yup, that's what I was misinterpreting. I was thinking of a closed walk, and writing cycle. It's late...
